# When printing multiple graphics, the last title is written at the bottom

Tags: python, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXMRc.png)I'm preprocessing a data and I've printed the graphs of certain variables one after the other. The title of each chart is at the top and the title of the last chart at the bottom. My code and graphics are as follows. How can I delete the bottom post. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
f,axes=plt.subplots(7,1,figsize=(20,15))                                   
sns.distplot(df['Temperature(F)'],ax=axes[0]).set_title('Temperature(F)')                                                                
sns.distplot(df['Wind_Chill(F)'],ax=axes[1]).set_title('Wind_Chill(F)')                              
sns.distplot(df['Humidity(%)'],ax=axes[2]).set_title('Humidity(%)')        
sns.distplot(df['Pressure(in)'],ax=axes[3]).set_title('Pressure(in)')
sns.distplot(df['Visibility(mi)'],ax=axes[4]).set_title('Visibility(mi)') 
sns.distplot(df['Wind_Speed(mph)'],ax=axes[5]).set_title('Wind_Speed(mph)')
sns.distplot(df['Precipitation(in)'],ax=axes[6]).set_title('Precipitation(in)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the label for particular axes like this:

```
axes[6].set_xlabel('')
```